# How to group/aggregate/reduce third values of a python list/tuple by the first two values (without using for loops)?

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, aggregate, grouping, reduce

What is the best way to group/aggregate/reduce python tuples in the following manner (without using nested for loops).

For example, given the following tuples:

```
entry1 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product1')
entry2 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product2')
entry3 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product3')
entry4 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product1')
entry5 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product2')
entry6 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product3')
```

How can the function `func`:

```
func(entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6)
```

return the data in a similar format to:

```
(('name1', 'surname1', ('product1', 'product2', 'product3')),
('name2', 'surname2', ('product1', 'product2', 'product3')))
```

Notes:

- The order of results in not important.
- The results can be a list or a tuple
- Enforcing product uniqueness is fine however not required. That is results such as `('name1', 'surname1', ('product1', 'product1', 'product2', 'product3'))` are fine.

Comment: Why do `name2` and `surname2` come before `name1` and `surname1`?

Comment: Good point! I forgot to mention that order in the results is not important, updated the post to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group first and later convert to a list or tuple:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def func(*args):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for entry in args:
        d[entry[0], entry[1]].append(entry[2])
    return tuple((k[0], k[1], tuple(v)) for k, v in d.items())
```

Test:

```
entry1 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product1')
entry2 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product2')
entry3 = ('name1', 'surname1', 'product3')
entry4 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product1')
entry5 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product2')
entry6 = ('name2', 'surname2', 'product3')
print(func(entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5, entry6))
```

Result:

```
(('name1', 'surname1', ('product1', 'product2', 'product3')),
 ('name2', 'surname2', ('product1', 'product2', 'product3')))
```